# Convergence almost everywhere of characteristic functions

Tags: pr.probability, limits-and-convergence

Let $(\Phi_n)_n$ be the characteristic functions of probability measures $(\mu_n)_n$ and let $\Phi$ be the characteristic function of a probability measure $\mu$.

Do you know an example where $\Phi_n(t)\rightarrow\Phi(t)$ for all $t\in A$ where $A$ is dense in $\mathbf{R}^d$ but $(\mu_n)_n$ does not converge weakly to $\mu$ ?

Comment: By measure you mean probability measure or something more general?

Comment: Yes, $\mu_n$ and $\mu$ are probability measures.

Answer (score 5):

There is no such example. Let $(f_n)$ be a sequence of characteristic functions of probability measures $\mu_n$ which converges a. e. to a characteristic function $f$ of a probability measure $\mu$. You can always choose a subsequence such that $\mu_n\to\mu$ weakly to some measure on the real line (first theorem of Helly).
Then for this subsequence $f_n(x)\to f(x)$ for all $x$, where $f$ is the Fourier transform of $\mu$. Your assumption that $f$ is a Fourier transform of a probability measure implies that $\mu$ must be that probability measure. Since this works for
every subsequence we have convergence of $f_n$ to $f$ everywhere.

Comment: We need to assume that $(\mu_n)_n$ is tight to get this weak convergence.

Comment: No, one does not. If the limit measure is not a probability measure, then $f_n$ converges to its Fourier transform, which is not a characteristic function of a probability measure, but this contradicts your assumption.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I did not know this general version.

Comment: This is a great answer. However I think you are using $\mu$ and $f$ to denote two different objects, that are only proved to be the same at the very end, which is a bit confusing. (What I understand is that you start with a given limit for the c.f., then construct the c.f. of a limit, and then you prove they must be the same.)

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko In the OP, the convergence holds on a dense set (not necessarily a.e.). What happens then?

Answer (score 0):

If $\Phi_n\to\Phi$ pointwise on a dense subset, then by the Stone-Weierstrass theorem $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_B g\ d\mu_n = \int_B g\ d\mu $$ on every ball centered at $0$ and every $g\in C_0(\mathbb{R}^d)$. This implies that $\mu_n\to\mu$ in the weak$^{*}$ topology of the Banach space of bounded Borel measures $M(\mathbb{R}^d)$. However, we may not have that $\mu_n\to\mu$ in the weak topology of $M(\mathbb{R}^d)$. Let's be reminded that $\mu_n\to\mu$ weakly iff $\mu_n(E)\to\mu(E)$ for every Borel set $E\subseteq\mathbb{R}^d$.

For an example, let $\delta_a$ be the unit mass at $a\in\mathbb{R}^d$, i.e., $\delta_a(E) = 1$ if $a\in E$ and $\delta_a(E) = 0$ if $a\notin E$.  Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence with nonzero terms such that $a_n\to 0$. Let $\Phi_n$ be the charcteristic function of $\delta_{a_n}$ and $\Phi_0\equiv 1$ denote the characteristic function of $\delta_0$. Clearly, $$\Phi_n(\gamma) = e^{ia_n\gamma} \hspace{6mm}\forall\gamma\in\mathbb{R}^d$$ so $\Phi_n\to 1$ pointwise on $\mathbb{R}^n$. On the other hand, let $E$ be a set such that $0\notin E$ and $\{a_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}\subseteq E$. Then, $1=\delta_{a_n}(E)\not\to \delta_0(E)=0$, so $(\delta_{a_n})$ does not converge to $\delta_0$ weakly.

Comment: In your example $\delta_{a_n}\longrightarrow \delta_0$ weakly (by the continuity theorem, since $\Phi_n\longrightarrow \Phi_0$ pointwise).  Your reminder is incorrect: $\mu_n\longrightarrow \mu$ weakly iff $\mu_n(E)\longrightarrow \mu(E)$ for all $\mu$-continuity sets $E$. And here $E$ is clearly not a continuity  set of $\delta_0$ since $0\in \partial E$.

Comment: @esg After reading your comment and quick googling (e.g. Portmentau's theorem https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/sloan-school-of-management/15-070j-advanced-stochastic-processes-fall-2013/lecture-notes/MIT15_070JF13_Lec20.pdf) I realize that your description is indeed the same as the weak-star convergence or measures. "Weak convergence" of measures has just a different meaning in the Banach space language. Given the context, one must stick with the definition you've given.